# How useful is factoring large numbers - Not for cryptography!

Tags: factoring

This is a question for my curiosity.

Apart from its implications to cryptography. Is factoring large numbers really useful?

Are there any examples of where the ability to factor huge numbers, 1K bits plus would be useful?

Sorry if this is not really a mathematical question, but I reasoned someone with a maths background would be more able to answer this question. I guess I could have asked on physics forums as well.

Comment: In computer science, primes are useful for hashing.

Comment: @DeveloperChris: I would say not much at all. However, this may lead to some excellent spin-offs in algorithms, parallelization, optimization... and that is very useful. Look at the computational resources for this factoring challenge: http://math-fail.com/2010/01/the-232-digit-number-rsa-768-has-been-factored.html. If that can be reduced by a huge amount, it may lead to the very hot topic of data mining and big data analytics, which is currently the rage.

Comment: @MasterOfBinary You don't need factoring to get large primes.

Comment: You have to specify what you mean with "useful".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples:

Suppose you want to know all integers whose reciprocals in base $b$ have repeating digit patterns with period dividing $n$. This amounts to finding all factors of $b^n-1$, cf. the [Cunningham project](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/index.html). Likewise you may have given some integer $b$ and want to find all integers modulo which $b$ has multiplicative order dividing $n$. For example, with $b=2$, $n=2^k$, knowing suitable moduli would enable optimization of algorithmic details in FFT-based multiplications of long numbers. Again, this means factoring $b^n-1$, which for the choice $b=2$ and $n=2^k$ boils down to [factoring Fermat numbers](http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html): Note that $2^{2^k}-1 = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(2^{2^j}+1)$.

On the theoretical side, factorizations of numbers up to a few hundred decimal digits help raising the lower bound for odd perfect numbers, cf. [papers by Brent, Cohen and te Riele](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pub/pub116.html) and [the oddperfect project](http://oddperfect.org/).

Comment: I have chosen this as the most 'correct' answer given the question and no other candidates. It would seem the answer is there is no real need for factoring large primes (apart from crypto) The oddperfect and Cunningham project seem to be no more than curiosities. Please feel free to contradict me if they add some important component to math and science.